# Capture Max Response Time of parallel requests using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have three requests Req1,Req2,Req3 executed at same time.
So I have used parallel controller to execute the same.

Is there any way to capture Max response time of any of these requests in JMeter Summary report?
Because for reporting User Transaction that contains parallel requests, we need to take highest response time of these requests.
I used simplecontroller and placed Req1,Req2,Req3. But it captures Sum of these requests. Looking for some thing which will capture highest response time in JMeter Summary Report

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just tick `Generate parent sample` box:

[image]

This way in the [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener you will see one SampleResult containing execution time of the longest Sampler under the Parallel Controller:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  Can we also report http requests along with Longest sampler. This is really helpful to check the request takes long time. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Any inputs on above query. Appreciate your help